# Cant set NSString in a Singleton class from another view iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, singleton

I have a singleton which has a property string called duration and is synthesised.

```
MySingleton.h

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *duration

MySingleton.m

@synthesize duration;

+ (id)sharedManager {
static MySingleton *sharedMyManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

    duration = @"Default Property Value";
}
return self;
}
```

I set the strings initial value above. This all works fine. Now from another viewController view1 below I have a method that I call where I want to update the duration string in the Singleton to another value like below which it is doing so correctly

```
- (void)updateString
{

MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton sharedManager];
singleton.duration = @"abc";
}
```

Now from a 2nd view if I call [sharedManager duration]; its getting the initial set value not the one I set from view1 which should say @"abc"; in viewDidLoad of second view I call

```
sharedManager = [[MySingleton alloc]init];
NSLog (@"The duration??? = %@", [sharedManager duration]);
```

Comment: in init shouldn't it be like `if (duration!=nil) {
return duration;
} else{ self = [super init] {

    duration = @"Default Property Value";
}
return self;
}`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Why would you check if `duration` is set in the code for the `init` method.

Comment: @rmaddy: i have seen many singleton classes' init containing these codes.

Comment: That's called "cargo cult programming". duration is a property of this class. super doesn't know anything about it, so [super init] cannot set it.

Comment: Ooops... It's a singleton. You shouldn't call [[MySingleton alloc] init], but always, always, always call [MySingleton sharedManager].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is wrong as proven by the following code, which allows you to change the string.
Maybe you are not calling your singleton as `[MySingleton sharedManager]` and instead you are calling `[MySingleton new]`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySingleton : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *duration;
@end

@implementation MySingleton

+ (instancetype) sharedManager {
    static MySingleton *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [self new];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _duration = @"Default Property Value";
    }
    return self;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [MySingleton sharedManager].duration = @"abc";
        NSLog(@"%@",[MySingleton sharedManager].duration); // abc
    }
}
```

Also, note that the @property NSString should be copy, not strong, and that @synthesize is not needed (a @synthesize varname = _varname is added by default), and that setters have a lowercase s, as in `setDuration:`.

Comment: please see my edits I can set the variable however when I call it from a 2nd view it reverts to old value not the value set form view 1

Comment: Because the original class goes out of scope. Well, if you two pairs of {} surrounding the two lines inside the @autoreleasepool, my example keeps working. As posted above, you are calling [[MySingleton alloc]init] which is the same as [MySingleton new], therefore creating a second instance. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: in 2nd view i changed to sharedManager = [MySingleton sharedManager]; but I still get old value

Comment: I was re-allocing the singleton in every class that I accessed it I have set them all to sharedManager = [MySingleton sharedManager]; and now it works as you say I creating multiple instances of the singleton...oops

Comment: hi jano, May i know why @property(NSString *duration) should be copy, why not its to be strong?

Comment: @dineshsurya http://stackoverflow.com/a/14008370/412916 it's just a good practice.